# Как определить, произойдет ли у элемента css transition? Метод стандартной библиотеки или алгоритм

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Необходимо удалить элемент со страницы. Сейчас на этот элемент навешивается обработчик события `transitionend`, коллбэк которого (удаление элемента) срабатывает, когда transition завершается.

Проблема в том, что пользователь сам решает, нужны ему переходы (transitions) или нет. И если пользователь решил, что не нужны и не добавил их в стили, то, соответственно, событие `transitionend` никогда не случится и элемент никогда не будет закрыт.

В первую очередь я предположил, что навешивание хоть какого-нибудь `transition` решит проблему (пусть даже duration === 0), но, как оказалось, даже в данном случае событие не происходит.

Поэтому я решил, что сначала нужно как-то определить, есть ли вообще у элемента такое css-свойство. И, если его нет, то удалять элемент сразу, без навешивания обработчика `transitionend`.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это сделать. Порыв немного интернет выяснил (не знаю правда, насколько информация актуальна), что встроенного метода для проверки *нет*.

Возможно, сейчас уже ситуация изменилась. Но, если нет, то прошу предоставить примерный алгоритм функции определения.

Comment: Ну добавь эти свойство в какой нибудь класс и дай класс тем элементам в котором нужны, и если есть класс то удалишь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, алгоритм довольно прост: необходимо всего лишь получить высчитанные стили для элемента при помощи `window.getComputedStyle(e)`, после чего проверить свойство `transitionDuration` полученного объекта, чтобы оно было больше 0. Если это так, то навесить обработчик `transitionend`. В противном случае удалить элемент без обработчика.

Небольшое замечание: время, содержащееся в этом свойстве является **строкой**, оканчивающейся на "s" или "ms". Поэтому придется воспользоваться функцией `window.parseInt()`, чтобы извлечь оттуда число.

Не знаю, насколько точен и безошибочен этот алгоритм, но, вроде бы, мои нужды он покрывает. Но я готов с удовольствием выслушать возможные недостатки такого подхода.

Тем не менее, если окажется, что для этих же целей существует специальный метод, то мое предпочтение будет отдано именно ему.

Comment: `transitionDelay` всего лишь обозначает паузу перед началом анимации и никак не зависит от её наличия или отсутствия

Comment: @andreymal описка. Хотел написать про transitionDuration. Сейчас подправлю. Спасибо за указание!

Comment: А вот по `transitionDuration` действительно можно определять наличие анимации, ага. Хотя, наверно, не исключён вариант, когда он ненулевой, но сами анимашки отключены где-то на уровне браузера, но я с таким не сталкивался

Comment: @andreymal я даже больше скажу. Не уверен, что отключение переходов (анимаций) на уровне браузера вообще возможно. Хотя, могу ошибаться. Но в любом случае, мне кажется, это не то, о чем стоит беспокоиться.